# .animate() - how to change animation end in progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Goal:
Scroll the window smoothly with `PageUp` and `PageDown` keys.

- **1 press**: page scrolls **1** unit.
- **n quick presses**: page scrolls **n** units.

Let unit = 160px.

I press `PageDown`. Page starts scrolling to 160px, let's say it's 90px now, while I press `PageDown` again. It's obvious I don't want to STOP animation here, I want to change it's target frame to point to 320px! So it actually should speed up and NOT STOP until the page is scrolled to 320px.

It seemed obvious to me that all I have to do is changing `tween` object within `step` function given to `.animate()` method as argument.

I wired up second `keydown` to modify `tween.end` property, but it didn't work. Animation just stuttered and stopped. The movement always ends at first unit.

The x.stop().animate(...) approach is "no-no". More hickup - unacceptable. There must be a way to change animation end during the process without stopping it, slowing it down or any other unwanted artifacts.

Ok, here's the code:

```
var isScrolling = false;
var scrollStartPosition = 0;
var scrollTargetPosition = 0;

function goTo(position) {
    if (isScrolling) {
        scrollTargetPosition = position;
        goToUpdate();
    }
    else {
        scrollStartPosition = scrollTargetPosition = position;
        position = position >= 0 ? (position <= pageEnd ? position : pageEnd) : 0;
        $(page).animate({ scrollLeft : scroll = position }, { start: goToStart, step : goToStep, complete : goToComplete, duration : 500 });
    }
}

function goToStart(arg) {
    isScrolling = true;
}

function goToUpdate() {
    // ???
}

function goToStep(n, tween) {
    isScrolling = true;
    if (scrollTargetPosition !== scrollStartPosition) {
        scrollStartPosition = tween.end = scrollTargetPosition;
    }
}

function goToComplete(arg) {
    isScrolling = false;
}
```

Please, help :) I've wasted ca 8h experimenting with this with no luck. `jQuery.animate()` seems completely ignoring any atempt to change animation in progress, the only thing I succeeded to do is to stop and restart it. I also managed to queue subsequent moves, but the total movement was just FUGLY n jumps instead one normal move.

Comment: Why do you need this behaviour? Pressing the up/down arrows scroll the page anyway. Have you given consideration to what should happen when the caret is inside a textarea? Or what impact this will have on accessibility for people who only use a keyboard to browse?

Comment: It's a special effect, experimental project. More than a demo / showcase than anything else. I'm experimenting with responsive reflowed layouts, similar to those in Windows (Modern) News Reader App.

Comment: Please do not add your solution to your question. Post it as an answer instead and accept it after the delay. This way, your question will be properly resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just described how to do it for free ;) It actually works as expected, I missed one very ugly bug in `position` parameter calculation. It just didn't change with pressing the keys.

Here's fixed `goTo()` function:

```
function goTo(position) {
    if (isScrolling) {
        scroll = scrollTargetPosition = position;
        goToUpdate();
    }
    else {
        scrollStartPosition = scrollTargetPosition = position;
        position = position >= 0 ? (position <= pageEnd ? position : pageEnd) : 0;
        $(page).animate({ scrollLeft : scroll = position }, { start: goToStart, step : goToStep, complete : goToComplete, duration : 500, queue : false });
    }
}
```

The only difference is scroll variable (defined elsewhere) set to the new position after registering the event.

**Now it works beautifully.**

BTW, if we want use that kind of effect without breaking accessibility - it should be activated with some conditions met first. In my code the screen resoultion is checked. If it's over 1280px wide - I activate special animated view.

**So, here's complete solution:**

```
// create a very wide page
// include jQuery and this...

var page;
var pageEnd;
var scroll;
var scrollStep = 160;
var isScrolling = false;
var scrollStartPosition = 0;
var scrollTargetPosition = 0;

function goTo(position) {
    if (isScrolling) {
        scroll = scrollTargetPosition = position;
    }
    else {
        scrollStartPosition = scrollTargetPosition = position;
        position = position >= 0 ? (position <= pageEnd ? position : pageEnd) : 0;
        $(page).animate({ scrollLeft : scroll = position }, { start: goToStart, step : goToStep, complete : goToComplete, duration : 500, queue : false });
    }
}

function goToStart(arg) {
    isScrolling = true;

}

function goToStep(n, tween) {
    isScrolling = true;
    if (scrollTargetPosition !== scrollStartPosition) {
        scrollStartPosition = tween.end = scrollTargetPosition;
    }
}

function goToComplete(arg) {
    isScrolling = false;
}

function keyDown(e) {
    var handled = true;
    switch (e.which) {
        case 33:
        case 38:
            goTo(scroll - scrollStep);
            break;
        case 34:
        case 40:
            goTo(scroll + scrollStep);
            break;
        case 35:
            goTo(pageEnd);
            break;
        case 36:
            goTo(0);
            break;
        default:
            handled = false;
            break;
    }
    if (handled) e.preventDefault();
}

function init() {
    page = $('body');
    pageEnd = page[0].scrollWidth - page[0].clientWidth;
    page.scrollLeft(1);
    if (page.scrollLeft() < 1) page = $('html');
    goTo(0);
    $('html').css({
        'overflow-x' : 'scroll',
        'overflow-y' : 'hidden'
    });
    scroll = page.scrollLeft();
    $(window).keydown(keyDown);
}

$(init);
```